# Is there any way to see messages written to Console.Error from a WinForms application?

Tags: .net, stderr

In my winforms app, I'm using a 3rd party library that logs to Console.Error.

```
Console.Error.WriteLine("some error message");
```

Is there some tool I can use to see these messages?  I only want to see them while developing/debugging.

I thought debugview might do it, but it only shows Trace messages.  Also, Visual Studio's "Output" window does not show it either (when attached to the process).

If there are no tools, how about a way to redirect StdErr to Trace logs?

Comment: Usually, if the 3rd party library is a *library* it should run within your own process and you should see the Console output including errors in your VS console as you expected. Is the 3rd party library an executable, and if so, how do you run it from your WinForms app?

Comment: Its a .net DLL, open source, so I'm looking at the code.

Comment: This is already taken care of by the Visual Studio Hosting Process.  You'll need to write your own app instead of attaching the debugger to some kind of demo app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`Console.SetError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.seterror.aspx) to redirect output to your own `TextWriter` - which could in turn use `Trace` or `Debug`, or possibly write to a virtual console within your app.

Comment: This worked, and I found this post as an example of making your own TextWriter: http://consoleredirect.codeplex.com/  I just pushed all output to Trace.